# How to extract values between two strings in a text file in python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a  text file where data is generating in between two strings. Now, I want to extract the data from the text file. Can anyone help me how to extract data here? I have tried with the following code but it's not working.

```
TEXT FILE
<velocity> 5 "momentum1 |x_value@lin |y_value@log"
  +1.0000000e+00   +1.5000000e+00   +1.8060150   +0.0000000
  +1.5000000e+00   +2.5000000e+00   +0.0000000   +0.0000000
  +2.5000000e+00   +3.5000000e+00   +0.0000000   +0.0000000
  +3.0000000e+00   +4.5000000e+00   +0.0000000   +0.0000000
  +3.5000000e+00   +5.5000000e+00   +0.0000000   +0.0000000
<\velocity>

<velocity> 5 "momentum2 |x_value@lin |y_value@log"
.
.    datas
.
.
.
<\velocity>
```

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

with open('mydata.txt') as infile, open('momentum1.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    currentstate = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "<velocity> 5 momentum1 |x_value@lin |y_value@log":
            currentstate = True
            continue
        elif line.strip() == "<\velocity>":
            currentstate = False
            continue
        elif currentstate:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Get the index of the start and the end of the value, and cut it off. Use a special character for it, like $$ before the value, and ^^ for the end - and cut it out

Comment: You should check `if currentstate:`, not using an `elif` against `line.strip()` equality checks

Comment: Also, the first line is `"<velocity> \"5 momentum1 |x_value@lin |y_value@log\""` if you plan on comparing it exactly

Comment: What isn't working with the code you tried? What happens when you run it? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Your text file format is very unusual, and far from ideal. Why is it this strange combination of almost XML plus space-separated values? Do you have any control over the format?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice   I want to take the data in-between '<velocity> 5 "momentum1 |x_value@lin |y_value@log" and  <\velocity>' then I want to put that data in a new file. After running my code I got my new file without any data there

Comment: @jarmod I don't have control over the format

Comment: It looks like you made a small mistake as others have pointed out: the string you are searching for has quote characters. To figure out things like this on your own, you can debug your code. If you are unfamiliar with debugging, I suggest you check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips to get you started.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice okay I will do so

Answer (score 0):

You could also read it as a single string and then use a split statement possibly? For ex.:

```
import re

values = []
with open('mydata.txt') as infile, open('momentum1.txt', 'w') as outfile: 
    currentstate = False
    for line in str(infile):
      for y in str(line).split(' '):
         if re.search('+', y):
            values.append(y)
```

You could then choose how you output it, using a join statement, or else just a loop.

Comment: I have tried this one as well but there is some error in the if statement. "error: nothing to repeat at position 0"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some `\"` characters in your if statement that sets `currentState` to `True`. In the same way, you forgot an anti-slash before your anti-slash inside the first elif. This code should works:

```py
with open('mydata.txt') as infile, open('momentum1.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    currentstate = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "<velocity> 5 \"momentum1 |x_value@lin |y_value@log\"":
            currentstate = True
            continue
        elif line.strip() == "<\\velocity>":
            currentstate = False
            continue
        elif currentstate:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Now, I did same but still my output file is blank

Comment: yes, it's working, I have done a small mistake again!  thank you